# JS: Image onLoad resize... How to?

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript.
I want to create simple script, that will be resize loaded image using css width and height.
Here is code example:

```
       <img style="width:200px; height:200px" 
src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-desktop-1440x900-a.png" onLoad="    
    //need resize code here
    "/>​
```

I'm trying to resize image with original size ratio. But I can't access original size. When I want to select original size by `this.height` it gives me css size. And where to find original value? And how to change size? `this.style.height = '200px'` ????

Comment: Does setting `style.width = 'auto'` and `style.height = 'auto'` first and then measuring it work?

Comment: put it as <img width="200" height="200" then access with .height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `max-width` and `max-height` in the CSS instead?

```
<img style="max-width:200px; max-height:200px" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-desktop-1440x900-a.png"/>​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6KfWB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frMjh/). The only issue is that the `naturalWidth/Height` properties are not supported by Opera and IE < version 9 (according to [dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljavxihg.php)).